# Specifying single colour by panel for base R pairs() plot?

Tags: r, plot, visualization

I wondered if there is a way by which scatterplot point colours can be allocated to specific panels using the custom panel function capabilities of base R's `pairs()` plot? There are plenty of examples of colouring by factor *within each panel*, but I can't find anything whereby a single colour can be allocated to **all** points in a given panel, and a different colour to the points in another. There is probably something clever which can be done by accessing the indices of the paired combinations of columns, and getting `pairs()` to pass that to a custom panel function, but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a terrible hack, but you can do it by searching up the call stack for the row/column indices of the current panel ...

```r
pp <- function(x, y) {
    ## extract panel indices
    i <- parent.frame(2)$i
    j <- parent.frame(2)$j
    col <- if (i==1 && j == 3) "red" else "black"
    points(x, y, col = col)
}
pairs(mtcars[,1:5], panel = pp, gap = 0)
```

What is `parent.frame(2)` doing? Here is the call stack when `pp` is called (gotten by saying `debug(pp)`, then issuing `where` from within the debugging environment):

```
where 1: upper.panel(...)
where 2: localUpperPanel(as.vector(x[, j]), as.vector(x[, i]), ...)
where 3: pairs.default(mtcars[, 1:5], panel = pp, gap = 0)
where 4: pairs(mtcars[, 1:5], panel = pp, gap = 0)
```

`parent.frame(2)` means "retrieve the environment two steps up the call stack", i.e. the environment of `pairs.default`. `pairs.default` runs a `for` loop over the row (`i`) and column (`j`) indices, and so we can retrieve the current values of those indices from that environment. I figured this out by putting a `browser()` statement inside my `panel` function, then inspecting the contents of the environment one level up (`ls(parent.frame(1))`), not finding anything that looked like row/column indices, and trying `ls(parent.frame(2))` ...

Comment: Thanks, Ben! Could you clarify what is happening with the `parent.frame()` function(?)?

Answer (score 1):

With `pairs` I don't know. But you can use the **GGally** package to plot a customized plot matrix. Here is an incomplete example:

```r
library(GGally)

gg1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) + 
  geom_point(col = "red")
gg2 <- ggplot() + geom_blank()
gg3 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) + 
  geom_point(col = "blue")
gg4 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Petal.Width)) + 
  geom_point(col = "green")

ggmatrix(
  list(gg1, gg2, gg3, gg4), 
  2, 2,
  c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"),
  c("Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"),
  byrow = TRUE
)
```

[image]